# Receive SMS with iMessage on multiple Macs

Tags: macos, iphone, icloud, messages, sms

I have 2 Macbooks, one old, one new. Both are configured to be able to receive the SMS of my iPhone and cell number through iMessage.

However, **only** the old Macbook is receiving SMS, while both old and new Macbook receive regular iMessages configured with my Apple iCloud ID.

When I got the new Macbook, I stopped using the old one, and could receive SMS with the new one freshly configured. At one point, when I used the old Macbook **again** after some time, the new Macbook stopped receiving SMS altogether.

Is there maybe a limit to how many Macs can receive the same SMS through one iPhone?

Comment: Have you checked the settings on both devices? Message settings on iOS and the settings window (CMD + ,) in messages on your new Mac

Comment: @Harcker, you're right, there is a forwarding setting in iOS. I wonder how I missed that in the settings jungle..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the settings on both devices? Message settings on iOS and the settings window (CMD + ,) in messages on your new Mac?

Text message forwarding happens on the following iOS settings page for iMessage:

[image]